# What is the impact of F5 loadbalancer on session timeout in an asp.net mvc2 app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have implemented the showing alert message for  Session timeout  in an asp.net mvc2 application using the following article with some customization as per the requirement:

http://fairwaytech.com/2012/01/handling-session-timeout-gracefully/

along with the following session state mode:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=StudentsDB;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false" timeout="30" compressionEnabled="true" sqlCommandTimeout="240" />
```

Forms timeout=15 and Sessiontimeout = 30

The application is running fine in my development and devintegration environment(with no loadbalancer in both the environments.

When I deployed the application in QA and Staging environment where there is F5 loadbalancer configuration available it started behaving weirdly.

For some users the alert pop up comes and some other users it does not appear at all and sometimes it logs out automatically.

The functionality is not running properly and behaving weird manner.

There are no  sticky sessions enabled on F5 loadbalancer.

In Global.asax.cs file I have the following code :

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Only access session state if it is available
        if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
        {
            //If we are authenticated AND we don't have a session here.. redirect to login page.
            HttpCookie authenticationCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authenticationCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authenticationCookie.Value);
                if (!authenticationTicket.Expired)
                {
                    //of course.. replace ANYKNOWNVALUEHERETOCHECK with "UserId" or something you set on the login that you can check here to see if its empty.
                    if (Session["IsSessionValid"] == null)
                    {
                        //This means for some reason the session expired before the authentication ticket. Force a login.
                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl, true);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

I tried to check the code and all the things on my devlopment and devintegration environment and found nothing much.
Can anyone help me to know the possible reasons for the above mentioned issue?

Thanks &  Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For troubleshooting the issue, I asked the infrastructure guy to stop on of the server and keep the other server up and running. On validating the issue we found that session timeout warning functionality is working as expected. By this, I made sure that there is no impact of F5 loadbalancer on the session timeout functionality. On analysis I found that I have no machinekey tag in the web.config and after going through some articles as mentioned below :

http://aspalliance.com/383_SQL_Server_Session_State_on_a_Web_Farm
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LoadBalancingAndASPNET.aspx
http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/aspnet-and-load-balancing

I included the machinekey tag and prepared the package and deployed it on both the servers and then validated the functionality once again. I found that the functionality worked as expected.